# Saspy Table Names in the Library

Tags: python, sas, saspy

I want to use `SASPy` to put the names of tables within a library into a list as strings.

I tried this but `sasdata()` module does not work on my computer:

```
sas = saspy.SASsession()

tables = sas.sasdata(library=library_name).list_tables()

for table in tables:
    print(table)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list_tables()` is a method of the SAS session object. The way you're using this is not a valid use of `sasdata()`. The corrected code is below.

```
sas    = saspy.SASsession()
tables = sas.list_tables('sashelp')

for table, typ in tables:
    print(table)
```

```
AACOMP
AARFM
ADSMSG
AFMSG
AIR
AIRLINE
...
```